# UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities error while submitting to appstore

Tags: ios, healthkit

I have revamped my old application to use healthKit as base and hence I added healthKit as required device capability and moved up the deployment target to iOS 8.0 to make sure that healthKit is available and from iPhone4s all the devices support iOS 8.0 and healthkit.

My app is build for iPhone (not a universal app). Now when I try to submit the app I am getting the below error.

*“The app's Info.plist can't contain values for the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key that would prevent this app from opening on any iOS device that was supported by previous versions. For more information, see Understanding the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities Key.”*

Does that mean, I need to remove healthkit capability and write code to support iPhone4 also ?? Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem on an iPhone only target, and resolved the issue by removing the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key.

Comment: but did Apple approve?  I did remove it and uploaded but app is still in review

Comment: @anoop4real We didn't experience any problems during review. The app is in the store.

Comment: Thanks, we had an issue with app description, just updated and informed Apple, hope it gets approved soon

Comment: Got it approved :)